# Error 503 Backend fetch failed Backend fetch failed Guru Meditation: XID: 45654 Varnish cache server

Tags: magento2, varnish

we are using MAgento 2.1 and elastic suite ,rediss cache and varnish cache 4

so we have 60 K products in our site and recently we updated attribute in magento2 admin from that day onwords we are getting error like

> Error 503 Backend fetch failed
>   Backend fetch failed
>   Guru Meditation:
>   XID: 45654
>   Varnish cache server

so we updated varnish config with below :

```
-p http_resp_hdr_len=65536 \
 -p http_resp_size=98304 \
```

then also same error trigger so please do the needful

Comment: you should contact your hosting to solve this issue, it seems like your varnish is unable to handle http post data size

Comment: as of now we only taking care of  all with gcloud

Comment: which webserver you use? a Guru Meditation could leave error info in webserver logs

Comment: we are using google cloud

Comment: check error log